# How to set up Azure Service Bus topic with NoMatchingSubscriptionException and an AuditTrail Subscription

Tags: azureservicebus

I would like a subscription that receives all messages sent to the topic.
And I would like a subscription that receives all messages that haven't matched a filter on other existing subscriptions. I can get one or the other but not both at the same time.

In basic examples of creating a topic with subscription, the subscription has a default rule with a filter of 1=1. ie all messages sent to that topic will go to that subscription. The examples suggest this subscription could be used as an audit trail for that subscription. But if you keep that rule then its not possible to set up `EnableFilteringMessagesBeforePublishing` with `NoMatchingSubscriptionException`

Is the following scenario possible?

PostTopic
 - `Subscription-MessageType-Known` gets all messages where MessageType property is set. 
 - `Subscription-NoFilter-Matched` gets all messages which do not match any other filter on this topic
 - `Subscription-Audit-Trail` gets all messages sent to this topic

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out of the box.  The only way you could do this, is by being creative with the filters for yourself.  So, you have you 'known filters' and then a complex, aggregated filter to compose that matches only when the others are not matched.

Another thing that we have done in the past (and where we controlled the sender side!) was to cache the filters on the topic that we were sending to.  And to match our message against these filters first (on the client side).  If we had a match, we knew we had a subscription, if not, we could do our specific logic with it.  This however is only suitable if you can live with the small perf overhead and if you control the send side...

HTH